# AJAX broken after moving to Google Pagespeed Servers

Tags: ajax

Since I moved to Google Pagespeed servers my AJAX on my site has broken. The pages try to post and refresh the page instead of doing what Good 'ol AJAX does. It seems to not even be able to call the file in the POST part of my scripts. I am assuming because I have the url set to something like

```
url: "examples/suggestsentence.php?",
```

that maybe the pagespeed servers can find the file to cache? Im not sure whats going on here and even how to fix it without having to get off their servers.

Here is a url to check out http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/auto-azal/autocoid/

The bottom textarea is a ajax cal

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Please also do some basic debugging. Use your browser's developer tools. Are there JavaScript errors? Are the network requests for your Ajax calls showing up? What HTTP status do they have?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when pagespeed service take place add information to every request. To avoid these you should add a header directive in the web service url

In PHP it yould be like:

```
header("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));
```